# recommended Foley artist/studios for basic micro budget full length film?

Tags: sound-design, foley

I need to make an m&e mix for a previous feature film I've mixed 2 years ago without a full foley track.

Since now I must have a full foley recording, I'm looking for recommendations of a good studio/artist that you maybe have worked with and were happy with the results.

It's basically an indie movie, micro budget drama, 90 min, with no special demands just the regular steps, cloths and so on.

Comment: Hi Nimi, Welcome to Sound design. Although we certainly cover foley here, it's not meant to be a posterboard for jobs. Besides that, we're are you located and does that influence your choice of studios? Might be handy for anyone willing to advice you.

Comment: Hi there, and thanks. I'm sorry if i broke any rule, this was not supposed to be a job offer just a research among colleagues about good experience with foley artist/studios. but again, sorry if its inappropriate in any way.

Comment: as for the location, it doesn't really matter to me since it can be made online. thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure that we've completely come to a conclusion on product/service recommendations, though questions that establish how someone can identify a good vendor are generally preferable to asking for a list of vendor recommendations.  Since we do handle some recommendation questions, I think this can stay open for now though and see if it garners any interest from the community.

Comment: After over a month and no more than one low quality answer and almost no vote activity at all, I'm closing this as off-topic as it does not seem to be something the community has any interest in.  If you disagree, please head over to [Meta](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com) and open a question about it there so we can gather more insight from the community about this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend Rene from this community at Dallas Audio Post.

b

Comment: Why?  A little bit of explanation goes a long way :)  Have you worked with him before? Does his repertoire coincide with what the OP is looking for? etc.

Comment: nimi listed what he/she was looking for quite clearly. seems obvious that any recommendation made would need to fit that criteria. :)